# Adding linenoise library to nixpkgs

Tags: c, pkg-config, nix, nixos

I am on NixOS, trying to compile a c project which require the [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) library (which is an alternative to readline). But linenoise is not available in the nixpkgs.

So, I am trying to add it myself. At the moment I have this:

```
{ stdenv, fetchgit }:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "linenoise-${version}";
  version = "git-2016-09-30";

  src = fetchgit {
    url = "https://github.com/antirez/linenoise.git";
    rev = "c894b9e59f02203dbe4e2be657572cf88c4230c3";
    sha256 = "0wasql7ph5g473zxhc2z47z3pjp42q0dsn4gpijwzbxawid71b4w";
  };

  meta = {
    homepage = https://github.com/antirez/linenoise;
    description = "A minimal, zero-config, BSD licensed, readline replacement.";
    platforms = stdenv.lib.platforms.unix;
  };
}
```

I have 2 problems:

1: Linenoise is just a pair of c header/source files that are meant to be included directly in the project that uses linenoise. In other words, *there is no compilation to be done*, just adding these files should be enough.
With the current derivation is obviously tries to `configure/make/make install` but I simply don't know how to do otherwise.

2: Linenoise need to be accesible with pkg-config.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to bypass configure/make/make install steps in Nixpkgs. You can use `buildCommand` attribute, where you clearly specify HOW to transform source to package.

```
buildCommand = ''
  mkdir -p $out/include
  cp $src/linenoise.c $out/include/
  cp $src/linenoise.h $out/include/
'';
```

The trick with `$src` variable is simple too: almost every attribute you define in `mkDerivation` will be available in build command under same name. You could use `src_libnoise = fetchgit ...` and then refer to it as `$src_libnoise`.

As for pkg-config stuff, I don't know for sure if it respects `include` directory, so you have to figure out how pkg-config finds about it's includes.